# Online resource which has easy German to read with its English translation

Tags: resource, learning, expression, meaning-in-context

Is there any resource online which has easy German (should use most common words in daily setting) and also has its English translation alongside?

Comment: "easy" and "should use most common words" seem to contradict each other. Could you give some examples on the level that you are looking for?

Comment: It can include most common easy words, no contradiction.

Comment: @Gigili - Asking about beginner lesson and some easy text to read is totally different thing. The question you are mentioning is for those who don't know a bit about german and my question is for those who know a little bit about german but now wanted to increase their vocabulary and improve their reading skills in german.

Comment: @itsaboutcode: I proved that "easy" and "should use most common words" don't contradict each other, nothing to do with your question really.

Comment: @Gigili - I know that. I was answering to your possible duplicate comment.

Comment: Project Gutenberg provides lots of texts: http://www.gutenberg.org/browse/languages/de . Unfortunably, the selection is quite mixed and anything before 1900 is 'ye olde german', so I'm only posting this as a comment.

Answer (score 5):

The [German part of about.com](http://german.about.com) has a selection of dual-language texts. You will find them on [this page](http://german.about.com/library/bllesen_inhalt.htm). Note that not all of the texts are available in two languages, look for the ones marked *dual-language*.

However, they are not all elementary, but for example *Die Bremer Stadtmusikanten* should fit the bill. It even comes with German audio.

Comment: Do you mean "dual language readings"?

Comment: No, I meant a "reader" as in "reading exercise". Anyway, the text is much clearer after Tim's edit.

Comment: @Tim N - I think that would be an interesting reading. Any other text out there with same purpose?

Comment: @itsaboutcode: Stovner is the one who answered your question!

Comment: Just had a look at german.about.com and learnt a new word: *Rotationseuropäer*. Evil.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest taking a look at these Google Chrome / Chromium extensions that can make your life easier while learning german or english for that matter.

- [Google Dictionary](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja)
- [dict-cc](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nknonnojlmhnmjhpeokdbeineeajcemh)
- [Bubble Translate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jlhlebbhengjlhmcjebbkambaekglhkf)
- [After the Deadline](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fcdjadjbdihbaodagojiomdljhjhjfho)

Answer (score 2):

I copy-paste my answer to [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4917/magazines-and-documentaries-for-speaking-german-with-subtitles/4920#4920)

I'm not related to Yabla.

But I have appreciated their video demos very much. *There are subtitles, both german and english that you can switch on and off*. The speed of the video can be slowered. And all videos are done by genuine german people, and often real video content. I think something like 300 or more videos, i don't remember. You should at least [give a try there german.yabla.com](http://german.yabla.com). And I am tempted to subscribe personnally, I just wait to have a little more time during the week.

Answer (score 1):

I have learned quite a bit just reading the questions written in german.SE. Google Chrome recognizes the text and German and offers to translate. Then hovering the cursor over the English translation pops-up a little box with the original text.

While the translation is often a little imperfect, I have no problem getting the general idea. The well-written German is the key, as opposed to the poorer English.

Comment: I agree that a dictionary or machine translations usually are enough to understand a text in a language that you are learning. This solves the real problem though, not the one asked about :)

Comment: Google chrome translation service is very good and in fact I am using it daily to read "LEARN GERMAN WITH TOP-THEMA MIT VOKABELN" section of dw-world, but machine translation has some limitations, that's why I was looking for a text which was written with a purpose to teach english readers about german language.

Comment: Be very careful to only do this with original German text and english machine translation, not the other way around! :)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.linguee.de/ is a very good one.

It indexes web pages & documents, which is in dual language, so when you search, instead of a meaning of the word you can get full sentences and "learn" that word in contex.

Answer (score 1):

Here: http://www.has.vcu.edu/for/grimm/grimm_menu.html has dual-language text (among other resources!) for many Grimm stories.

Answer (score 0):

My german teacher plays Extr@ videos for us, you can find them all on youtube and i think they all have subtitles but I'm not sure. Just search youtube for "Extr@ in german" and they should come right up.